# image that changes according to the link (make an include in js (as in php))

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have 3 identical page only a banner changes on the 3 pages in html, I'd like to put in a file js this part of code to have only one function call and that in my js every time I am on such a page he calls me the right banner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
        <img id="image0" src="page1" /> 
        <a href="eurasanté.html" onclick="changeImage(this);">TEXTE</a>
        <a href="euratech.html" onclick="changeImage(this);">TEXTE</a>
        <a href="index.html" onclick="changeImage(this);">TEXTE</a>   
</body>
<script src ="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

and Js

```
const page1 = index.html;
const page2 = euratech.html;
const page3 = eurasanté.html;
function changeImage(element)
{
  let changeUrl = element.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0);
  let img = changeUrl.getAttribute("src");
    if(img === page1)
    {
        img = "2BOA-305.jpg";
    }
    if(img === page2)
    {
        img = "574b5545444ea.jpg";
    }
    if(img === page3)
    {
        img = "e233b0f310e17d1d40f1d3d49cb7d5a1.jpg";
    }

  changeUrl.setAttribute("src", img);
}
```

I have nothing that throws me I'm afraid of having an error :/